# Reduce memory usage of UILabel

Tags: ios, memory, uilabel

Typically, Memory usage of `UILabel` is not so big problem.

However, In the widget, It matters a lot!, Because we can use only 10MB memory for each iOS extensions.

All my logics and models can be optimized by myself, However the problem is the `UIViews` from Apple.

1. All `UIView` that overrides `drawRect:` will be backed by raster image. So View size matters memory consumption. Just container `UIView` does not use raster cache.
2. `UILabel` also backed by raster image since Core Text does so.
3. When an `UILabel` breaks lines of given text 1 to 2, It will uses 2 times more memory even the content of second line is very small. Because entire content are backed by raster image.
4. iPhone6+ and iPhone6S+ plus have 3x scale raster image. So, `UILabel` on iPhone6+ and 6S+ uses 2.25 times more memory than iPhone5 even they are visually same size. ((3*3) / (2*2)).
5. Even more, iPhoneX+ has much wider screen, So line breaking for `UILabel` which is fit to screen width will causes huge memory consumption. As a result, iPhoneX+ typically needs 3~4 times more memory then iPhone 5.

So, Using multiple labels in the widget extension can be dangerous for 3x scaled iPhoneX+ Users, iOS will kill the extension which exceed harsh memory limitation.

I tried:

- Turn off raster backing. (No way found)
- Use low level core text API. (Same result)
- Make `UILabel`s small as possible using layout constraint. (It works, however, sometime user content matters)

I want to reduce memory usage with keeping amount of content to display.

Any suggestions, recommendations and abstract strategies will be welcomed.

Comment: If what you say is true, Widget Extensions are broken and should be avoided, unless of course you haven't actually seen a memory problem?

Comment: It's true. I did fight with this problem for 2 years. You can check the detailed problem and my half answer for it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195320/too-often-unable-to-load-in-today-widget-extension/31529428#31529428.

Comment: I would dump them then; they cannot be worth 2 years of effort.

Comment: iOS kills the extension when it exceed memory restriction by design. There is no crash report or chance to dump, Because it is not a crash, just normal killing by iOS like as iOS kills old background apps to ensure memory. Xcode just alerts "Memory Error" It's all.

Comment: Anyway, the point of this question is reducing memory of `UILabel`, Not extension limitation. The memory limitation is reasonable, and I can agree with Apple's decision(to keep alive many apps as possible). However, almost memory are occupied by `UIKit` that's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your iOS base version but has a little trick to reduce the memory consumption if your **UILabel** is **monochrome** do you change the **CALayerContentsFormat** to **kCAContentsFormatGray8Uint** it means that you use (1 byte per pixel) instead (4 bytes per pixel) with **kCAContentsFormatRGBA8Uint**.

Sample in swift:

```swift
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    label.layer.contentsFormat = .gray8Uint
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind advice. Using layout configuration that makes UILabel uses small area as possible and setting contentsFormat will be very helpful IMO.